# verify cname record

Tags: c#, azure, dns, system.net

If I have the following CNAME records set up:

```
www.custom1.com     CNAME   www.myapp.com
www.myapp.com       CNAME   myapp.cloudapp.net
```

Will `Dns.GetHostEntry("www.custom1.com")` always return a HostName of myapp.cloudapp.net.

Essentially I'm allowing customers to use their own custom domains for an application hosted in Azure and would rather ask them to set up a CNAME record to my domain (e.g. www.myapp.com) than giving out the Azure hostname.

I'm just looking for a way to programatically check that the cname record has been set up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [DnDns library](http://dndns.codeplex.com/), it will allow you to do exactly what you are looking for.  The '[How to do a DNS Name Lookup](http://dndns.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20do%20a%20basic%20name%20lookup&referringTitle=Documentation)' documentation example should be easily adopted to your needs.  (The example involves an A record, but changing it to a CNAME would be easy).